# Unable to install Steam ( unmet dependencies )

Tags: steam

I'm new to Linux. I installed Steam on my desktop, but it doesn't work. It says that the following information may help to resolve this issue

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (=10 1.3-0ubuntu0.5) unable to correct problems, you may have broken packages."
```

How do I fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: To clarify you are which Ubuntu version? If you are using 12.04 which it sounds like you are. Try doing `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386`

Comment: and is it 64 or 32 bit system?

Comment: @ARG That will not matter in this situation. It is either a missing package dependency, or it is graphics driver based

Comment: I have a 64 bit version. I believe it's the latest version 12.04.

Comment: And if it is a graphics driver problem, does that mean it's a problem with my graphics card? Where would I go to fix this problem?

Comment: Try to run the following commands `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

If you get no errors then this

`sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6`

and lastly this

`sudo apt-get install steam -y`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't install Steam because of unmet dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/757723/cant-install-steam-because-of-unmet-dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

Do this.

Open up a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

and Remove steam by typing in this command

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge steam
```

Download and install steam off the site: Run these commands.

```
wget http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/archive/precise/steam_latest.deb
```

then install it.

```
sudo dpkg -i steam_latest.deb
```

then run steam in terminal

```
steam
```

and `steam` should start. You don't have to start steam by the command line its just for diagnostics.

Comment: Quick question, where do I run these commands?

Comment: Sorry i didn't know how new you where. open up a terminal by pressing Ctrl + Alt + T and type in the commands. dose it ask your question.

Comment: @Afriend did it help ?

Comment: It still did the same thing as last time