# Broken llvm-dev library?

Tags: package-management

Could any one tell me why there is a conflict in this package? and how do I resolve it?. Thanks.

[image: Synaptic Package Manager]

---

UPDATE: it is not broken, but there is a conflict that it cannot be installed. The dependency is as the following: `lllvm-dev -> llvm6.0-dev -> libtinfo-dev`

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>      libtinfo-dev : Depends: libtinfo5 (= 6.1-1ubuntu1) but 6.1-1ubuntu1.18.04 is to be installed
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

[image]

Comment: You created a *version conflict*. You told the system to install two packages, each of which depends upon a different version of some dependency. The most common reason is that the user added a non-Ubuntu or wrong-release source that provided an incompatible version of the software.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upgraded to 18.04 and now have many broken packages and unmet dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032126/upgraded-to-18-04-and-now-have-many-broken-packages-and-unmet-dependencies) According to the self-answer this is the correct duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

I follow the answer [for this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032126/upgraded-to-18-04-and-now-have-many-broken-packages-and-unmet-dependencies), and install aptitude. It allows me to downgrade `libtinfo5`, which fixes the dependency. This is actually great, I'm surprised aptitude has not been as popular as apt-get (at least for me.)